# Image crop and rotate for multiple images using dark room js

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, image-uploading

i used `darkroom.js` for cropping and rotating images in client side. Its working fine for single image but i want it for multiple images. Can anybody help on this issue or any other reference js for this purpose.

```
var dkrm = new Darkroom('#target', {
  // Size options
  minWidth: 100,
  minHeight: 100,
  maxWidth: 600,
  maxHeight: 500,
  ratio: 4/3,
  backgroundColor: '#000',

  // Plugins options
  plugins: {
    //save: false,
    crop: {
      quickCropKey: 67, //key "c"
      //minHeight: 50,
      //minWidth: 50,
      //ratio: 4/3
    }
  },

  // Post initialize script
  initialize: function() {
    var cropPlugin = this.plugins['crop'];
    // cropPlugin.selectZone(170, 25, 300, 300);
    cropPlugin.requireFocus();
  }
});
```

Here is the html

```
<div class="figure-wrapper">
      <figure class="image-container target">
        <img src="./images/domokun-big.jpg" alt="DomoKun" class="edit-img" id="target">
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="figure-wrapper">
      <figure class="image-container target">
        <img src="./images/domokun-big.jpg" alt="DomoKun" class="edit-img" id="target">
      </figure>
    </div>
```

I also changed the `id="target"` to `class="target"` but its not working for multiple

[Extensions url](https://github.com/MattKetmo/darkroomjs)

Answer (score 0):

This is not actually the answer for your question, but some kind of result of my little research on the theme.

First of all, I could not make Darkroom work with class attribute of images. There was js-mistake - it seems that Darkroom makes http-request with given selector (id in examples) to get the dom-element. If you give to him the current element from class from Jquery selection, it would not work.

I've made a little hack to deal with this situation. You can see it in this repo (made from standard Darkroom demo): https://github.com/renta/darkroomtest

As you can see, there are some troubles with this decision. It looks like a dirty hack and user changed his mind about the image editing - he could close Darkroom panel after clicking on its saving button.

Also I got a second way for solving this task. If anyone interested in it, I could put the code in public repo.

The keynote there:

- you have a gallery with several images;
- after click on current image there is an opening modal window with this image or its original (if image is the preview). For modal window I use this library https://github.com/samdark/the-modal (not the advertisement :) ). It has ability to make custom function on opening the modal window, where I can place the image and initiate the Darkroom lib on it.
- you save the image with Darkroom and close the modal window. After that you can easily update the image in the gallery, so user could see the result after closing the modal.

This variant is workable and has no problems of mass-editing approach.

Hope, that this answer will help someone.